# Banshee crashes at startup

Tags: 11.04, startup, banshee

Whenever I launch banshee, it loads the window and I can see it for 1-2 seconds before crashing without displaying any errors. I've tried uninstalling and installing via the banshee PPA with no luck. It was working before I rebooted my computer. It's not a corrupted DB or anything as I've renamed my old db and it still does the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried using rhythmbox which doesn't work either. seems to be a problem with my sound in ubuntu (i've tried several sound devices all with the same results)

Comment: Try starting banshee from a terminal. If it doesn't say anything useful, try it with the --debug option. This might help you figure out more information about the specifics of your problem. It could for example be a problem with an extension.

Comment: There are bugs related on launchpad.net → https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+question/154805 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/773495 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/529714

Comment: This question seems abandoned, marking to close.

Answer (score 0):

Does Banshee crash right after playing a song, or right after starting up? Try to disable all the plugins, then restart the application. Especially disable the iPod-support plugin. This plugin was the culprit for me when running Banshee on 10.10.